# C# How to put curly brackets in URL

Tags: c#, .net, api, facebook-graph-api

I've been trying to get the data that I need from Facebook's graph api explorer but unfortunately, cant pass the fields necessary in URL via C#.

Here's what I've tried so far

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com");

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync($"cocacola?fields=posts{id,created_time,permalink_url,message,link,type,full_picture}&access_token={textBox1.Text}").Result;
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            var jsonRes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);

            var returned = jsonRes.ToString();

            MessageBox.Show(returned);
        }
```

What's needed to be done here for fetching data via API? :)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The problem is the paranthesis, it returns: the name 'id' doesn't exist in the current context.  They are being treated as variables.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, there is an issue because you're using string interpolation and also want curly braces in your string. You'll have to escape them by doubling them.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync($"cocacola?fields=posts{{id,created_time,permalink_url,message,link,type,full_picture}}&access_token={textBox1.Text}").Result;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, the programs however I am getting 

Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error) 

Do you know why :)

Comment: You can ask another question describing that scenario so that it doesn't get mixed up with this and you'll get assistance in resolving that.

Answer (score 0):

***Your approach is incorrect Because Those Variables You Are Trying To Add In Url Are Actually Getting On String, You must escape them to get their value***
**Therefore Change**

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync($"cocacola?fields=posts{id,created_time,permalink_url,message,link,type,full_picture}&access_token={textBox1.Text}").Result;
```

**To**

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync($"cocacola?fields="+posts{id,created_time,permalink_url,message,link,type,full_picture}+"&access_token="+{textBox1.Text}).Result;
```

***But here to its incorrect cause i dont think `{textBox1.Text}` and `posts{id,created_time,permalink_url,message,link,type,full_picture}` Means Anything***